# action of cyclic group $n$ on $2n$ elements

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, cyclic-groups, symmetry

Let an 8-set $X$ represent the vertices of a cube: {$1,2,3,4$} is the label assigned to the four vertices at the "top"
and {$5,6,7,8$} is the label assigned to the four vertices at the "bottom"

a rotation of the cube wrt vertices can be defined as the permutation:
$$
\sigma = (1,2,3,4)(5,6,7,8).
$$
Like a cube kebab spinning! The permutation group $G$ generated by sigma has order 4:
$$
\sigma^2 = (1,3)(2,4)(5,7)(6,8); 
\sigma^3 = (1,4,3,2)(5,8,7,6); 
\sigma^4 = (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8).
$$
Is this group $G$ isomorphic to $C_4$? I can understand the action of $G$ on the 8-set $X$ as the natural action of a permutation group. But how would one define $C_4$ acting on $X$? Does $C_4$ act pairwise on $S =$ { {$1,5$},{$2,6$},{$3,7$},{$4,8$} }?

Thanks.

Comment: $G=\langle\sigma\rangle$ is naturally isomorphic to $C_4$ since $\sigma$ is of order $4.$ Its action on $X$ (or equivalently via this isomorphism, the action of $C_4$ on $X$) induces naturally an action on the powerset $\mathcal P(X)$, which restricts to an action on the set $\mathcal P_k(X)$ of subsets of $X$ of cardinality $k,$ for each $k$ from $0$ to $8.$ The action on $\mathcal P_2(X)$ restricts to $S.$

Comment: Use `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$.

Comment: More generally, it's always the case that a subgroup (in this case, a subgroup of $S_8$) generated by a single element of the group (in this case, $\sigma$) is necessarily cyclic.

Comment: $(1,2,3,4)(5,6,7,8)$ is a rotation of the cube about a face-center axis. There are two other families of axes of symmetry for the cube that provide different permutations of the vertices. Rotating around the axis through the center of opposite edges 41 and 67 yields the permutation $(1,4)(2,8)(3,5)(6,7).$ Rotating around the axis through opposing vertices 1 and 7 yields the permutation $(1)(2,5,4)(3,6,8)(7)$, yielding groups isomorphic to $C_2$ and $C_3$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

$G=\langle \sigma \rangle$ where $\sigma$ has order 4. Thus $G\cong C_4$.

I suppose you could say that the action of $c^i\in C_4$ on $G$ is $c^i\cdot \sigma^j = \sigma^i\sigma^j$.